# Must there be a "addLiquidityETH" txn for each token that is launched on PancakeSwap?

Tags: transactions, python, pancakeswap, liquidity-provider

I'm trying to automatically detect when liquidity is added for a token. For that I scan through pending transactions. However, I've noticed that for some launches there seems to be no `addLiquidityETH` or  `addLiquidity` transaction or at least I can't find it.

Therefore, I would like to as whether there must be a similar txn in general for tokens to be launched or is there also another way to provide liquidity and allow people to trade a coin?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to add liquidity without calling `addLiquidity`.

For example by copying the function `addLiquidity` and interacting directly with the Pair contract. A contract could add liquidity like this

```
    tokenA.transfer(pair, amountA);
    tokenB.transfer(pair, amountB);
    pair.mint(address(this));
```

Comment: ok thanks - makes sense. So, do you think mempool sniper bots  would  also detect such a way of adding liquidity?

Comment: @mc1893 It is possible, if getReserves return non-zero balances then the token pair has liquidity.

Comment: thanks for answering! yes that is the current way of how I check if liq. was added. However, I suppose this only is true after the txn has been proceesed. However, my understanding of a mempool bot has been that we look through pending txns and search for s.th. that looks like "adding liquidity". Then we could do a buy txn right in the same block. But I couldn't catch an "addLiquidity" or "addLiquidityETH" for serveral tokens launched on PCS.. :/

Comment: @mc1893 You've all the information needed. Although the a token pair could be controlled by a party that don't follow the rules. A contract is fully programable.